# Jquery follow scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a sort of sidebar on my website, which has to scroll down together with the user so that it is always in the view.

The code I'm using now is actually working fine however there is one problem. On smaller screens the sidebar scrolls before your at the sidebar thus making it impossible to see it all even if you scroll.

So what I want is the sidebar to scroll with the bottom instead of it being pushed down with the top so that when you reach the end of the sidebar it starts to scroll.

This is the code that I'm currently using.

```
var documentHeight = 0;
var topPadding = 10;
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#mainright").offset();
    documentHeight = $(document).height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sideBarHeight = $("#mainright").height();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            var newPosition = ($(window).scrollTop() - offset.top) + topPadding;
            var maxPosition = documentHeight - (sideBarHeight);
            if (newPosition > maxPosition) {
                newPosition = maxPosition;
            }
            $("#mainright").stop().animate({
                marginTop: newPosition
            });
        } else {
            $("#mainright").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the "best practice" for accomplishing a task like this is to use dynamically changing css position from `absolute` to `fixed` and vice versa. A basic example could look like:

```
$(function(){
   var $box    = $('.box'),
       offset  = $box.offset(),
       doc_h   = $(document).height();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            if(!$box.hasClass('fix'))
                $box.toggleClass('normal fix');
        }
        else{
            if(!$box.hasClass('normal'))
                $box.toggleClass('normal fix');
        }
    });
});​
```

Example in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/14/

Comment: I guess this isn't the OP wants

Comment: I'll try this one out - however I had hoped on a solution that was more like the code i have now, but with the box following the bottom instead of the top.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  var top = 50;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#box').stop().animate({ top: $(window).scrollTop() + top}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Try the example : **http://jsbin.com/omiyi3**

Comment: I'm not really seeing the difference between the one i've made and yours. The box still follows the top thus making the bottom unavailable on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can instead make the sidebar responsive by throwing your function into one of these:

```
if (responsive_viewport >= 768) {}
```

This makes it so that the function will only load if the viewport is bigger than or equal to 768px.