# JQuery create a scroll follow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok I have seen people using `position:fixed` to have a div follow the scroll.
I have also seen the following solution which is good ( [Jquery follow scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923511/jquery-follow-scroll) )  but I was wondering how I can accomplish 2 effects :

1. create a smooth scroll for the box
2. scroll the box inside a div (so if the scroll is higher than the holder div, the box should be on top of the div, and when you scroll down it should scroll inside)

an example of these features can be found here : http://www.limestonenetworks.com/dedicated_servers/order.html?id=47

but I cant figure out what they used and even if they used a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a slight alternative to Adam Hutchinson's

http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/JjuQu/

It's pretty self explanatory but just say if you need anything explained.

Comment: great, it worked perfect... I just want to also put a if statement to check and make sure that the box doesnt go out of the holder div.

Answer (score 0):

This div in the example is not polsition:fixed, or absolute. What they do is to animate the margint-top attribute on scroll relatively

Comment: are there any libraries available that I can use?? and if not how can I do achieve it?

Comment: to tell you the truth i don't know any libraries that do this as it's achieved by jQuery by itself. All you have to do is to detect scroll, and animate the division's margin according to the scroll position.. So it doesn't really require a library to do this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to map an event to the document scrolling and then move a div relative to the scroll. Something along these lines may give you somewhere to start.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $('#divtomove').css('top', $(document).scrollTop());
})
```

Comment: After looking at the other answer, it looks like you want to change margin-top rather than top in the css. So: .css('margin-top',$(document).scrollTop());

Comment: thanks, that works, but how can I achieve the animation and smoothness??

Answer (score 0):

Also, this is the code in the example page, just to get an idea

```
 var $scrollingDiv = $("#customize");
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 490) {
            if (($("#maincontentbox").height() - $(window).scrollTop()) > 0) {
                $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                    "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() - 500) + "px"
                }, "slow");
            }
        } else {
            $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                "marginTop": "0px"
            }, "slow");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

```
$('#divtomove').scrollFollow();
```